# How can I use just one on(change) function with multiple sliders?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

I have multiple noUISliders and I am wanting to have one on(change) function for all of them instead of one for each slider. The on(change) will essentially trigger the same function. Basically it will be some math that will add all the values of the sliders. Do I have to do a loop? I just have an alert in there for testing.

```
    var slider = $('#slider');
    var slider = slider[0];

    noUiSlider.create(slider, {
        animate: true,
        start: 41,
        step: 5,
        tooltips: [wNumb({decimals: 0})],
        connect: 'lower',
        range: {
            'min':0,
            'max': 1000
        }
    });


    var slider2 = $('#slider2');
    var slider2 = slider2[0];

    noUiSlider.create(slider2, {
        animate: true,
        start: 20,
        step: 1,
        tooltips: [wNumb({decimals: 0})],
        connect: 'lower',
        range: {
            'min':0,
            'max': 100
        }
    });


    var slider3 = $('#slider3');
    var slider3 = slider3[0];

    noUiSlider.create(slider3, {
        animate: true,
        start: 20,
        step: 1,
        tooltips: [wNumb({decimals: 0})],
        connect: 'lower',
        range: {
            'min':0,
            'max': 100
        }
    });

$('#slider')[0].noUiSlider.on('change',function(v,handle){

    alert("slider triggered");

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed create a little `jQuery.each()` loop to achieve your objective:

```
const start=[41,20,60],
 sliders=$("[id^=slider]").each((i,slider)=>{
 noUiSlider.create(slider, {
   animate: true,
   start: start[i],
   step: 5,
   tooltips: [wNumb({decimals: 0})],
   connect: 'lower',
   range: {'min':0,'max': i?100:1000}
 });
 // you can use the same loop to add an event handler to each slider:
 $(slider).noUiSlider.on("change",function(v,handle){
  console.log(`You just changed the slider with ID ${slider.id}.
The sum of all slider values is ${sliders.reduce((a,sl)=>+sl.value+a,0)}.`);
 });
}).get();
```

I used the ternary operator (`i?100:1000`) above so that a different parameter value would be applied for your first slider.

For the `start` values I changed it to picking a value from a globally defined array (`start`, see comments below!).

Comment: Wow that is cool! If I wanted to add different values for a 3rd slider would I just add another number like this?

start: i?20:41:60,

Comment: You can provide an array for the `start` values, like `start=[41,20,60]` and then pick the "right" value with `start[i]` within your loop instead of using the ternary operator.

Comment: This works so well!! Thanks a ton!!
So how would I trigger that onchange where I can just write it once?

Comment: Just changed my answer. Check it out ...